# BeautifulSoup how to extract text after <br> tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I don't know how to reach the following paragraph using BeautifulSoup and how to extract the particular text that I want. As I am new to Python and BS4.

My HTML is following:

```html
<div class="inner-content">
  <div class="bred"></div>
  <div class="clrbth"></div>
  <h1></h1>
  <h4></h4>
  ...
  ...
  ...
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p>

<!--This text I don't want -->

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    <br></br>


<!-- The text I want to extract using BeautifulSoup-->

    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

  </p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  ...
  ...
  ...
  <div class="bred"></div>
  <div class="clrbth"></div>
  <h1></h1>
 </div>
```

Please tell me how to extract the above mentioned text from my HTML. Thanks.

Comment: `print(''.join(soup.find('br').next_siblings))`

Comment: there is another `br` in other paragraphs also. Can you tell me how to reach the third paragraph and then I can use your above statement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [**`find_all()`**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) method and the [**`limit`**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#limit) argument to get the third `p` tag in your html. Next use the `.find` which return the first `br` tag in the third paragraph. From there you can use the [**`.next_siblings`**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-siblings-and-previous-siblings) method which return a [*generator object*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) and the [**`.join`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.join#str.join) function.

```
>>> third_p = soup.find_all('p', limit=3)[-1]
>>> ''.join(third_p.find('br').next_siblings)
```

Comment: sequence item 1: expected str instance, Tag found)

Comment: The error is likely because of the `BS` version you're using. I'm no longer updating my answers here. Feel free to edit it or post a new one. @WolfgangFahl