# Beautifulsoup extract string between BR but include <B>string</B>

Tags: beautifulsoup

```
<br>
Soccer:
<b>11</b>
<br>
Volley Ball:
<b>5</b>
<br>
Basketball:
<b>5</b>
<br>
Tennis:
<b>2</b>
<br>
```

i am trying to get the whole line like

```
Soccer : <b>11</b>
```

So far i am trying to use this code

```
for br in body.findAll('br'):
    following = br.nextSibling
    print following.strip()
```

but it only produce

```
Soccer:
Volley Ball:
Basketball:
Tennis:
```

Comment: try here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958517/beautifulsoup-how-to-extract-text-after-br-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this either with a similar approach you already started, or using a `regular expression`.

**Option #1**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<br>
Soccer:
<b>11</b>
<br>
Volley Ball:
<b>5</b>
<br>
Basketball:
<b>5</b>
<br>
Tennis:
<b>2</b>
<br>
"""

body = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

between_br = []
for br in body.findAll('br'):
    following = br.nextSibling

    if following == '\n':
        continue

    sport = following.strip()
    score = str(following.next_element)

    combined = ' '.join((sport, score))
    between_br.append(combined)

print '\n'.join(between_br)
```

**Option #2**

```
import re


html = """
<br>
Soccer:
<b>11</b>
<br>
Volley Ball:
<b>5</b>
<br>
Basketball:
<b>5</b>
<br>
Tennis:
<b>2</b>
<br>
"""

sports_regex = re.compile(r"""
 (?!<br>)  # Skip <br> tag
 (.*       # Match any character
 :\s       # Match a colon followed by a whitespace
 .*)       # Match any character
""", re.VERBOSE)

sports = sports_regex.findall(html)
print '\n'.join([s.replace('\n', ' ') for s in sports])
```

Both approaches will print:

```
Soccer: <b>11</b>
Volley Ball: <b>5</b>
Basketball: <b>5</b>
Tennis: <b>2</b>
```