# How to scrape P tags using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags

I have managed to scrape a website using the findAll function in beautiful soup with H2 / Class / Div tags. (e.g soup.findAll('div', {'class' : 'price'})
But there is one part of the website that has P tags which I'm not sure how to scrape. It has the below

Listing history

```
<p class="top">
    <strong>First listed</strong><br>
            800 on
```

I want the 800 but the Div Class "Sidebar sbt" has several entries on the website as does the p class = top.
Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: maybe try `print ''.join(soup.p.find('br')).strip().split()[0]` adopted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31959687/1248974

Comment: That doesn't work. I don't want to print the item. I want to define it e.g item_a = soup.findAll...
then do plant = item_a.get_text
How would i do that for the above P tag?

Comment: ok, sorry I didn't understand what you exactly wanted. I'll try again? you want to assign the result of `soup.find_all` to a variable? maybe `item_a =  soup.p.find('br')
print item_a.get_text()` ? returns the text of `u'\n            800 on\n'` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the **p** tags just as you would any other tag using BeautifulSoup:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> with open('html', 'r') as f:
...     soup = BS(f, "lxml")
... 
>>> soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'top'})
[<p class="top">
<strong>First listed</strong><br/>
            800 on
</p>]
```

using `soup.find_all` will produce a **ResultSet** if there is more than one tag. So from there you would do something like:

```
>>> p_tags = soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'top'})
>>> for tag in p_tags:
...     tag.get_text()
... 
'\nFirst listed\n            800 on\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the real case is just like the example

Try something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = """<div class="price">

 <p class="top">
     <strong>First listed</strong><br>
             800 on
 </p>
 <p class="top">
     <strong>First listed</strong><br>
             900 on
 </p>
 <p class="top">
     <strong>First listed</strong><br>
             1000 on
 </p>

 </div>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> div = soup.find_all('div', class_'price')
>>> for p_tag in div:
""" will search for all p tags in the div"""
...    p = p_tag.find('p', class_='top').text.split()[-2] 
""" will split the example with spaces and will make a list of result. if you want only the 800 use [-2]""" 
...    print(p)        
# 800
# 900
# 1000
```